# User seems to be imposing meaning on generic tag

Tags: discussion, tags

A user seems to want to give a generic tag, [lead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lead), a specific meaning:

- https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39229460/revisions
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13512322

However, it appears that only a minority of the questions with that tag have anything to do with the meaning being assigned, which is related to SQL; in fact, there doesn't really seem to be any consensus on the meaning.  The most popular questions are either related to SQL or sales/marketing.

The edits to the tag are gradually being approved.  Is it acceptable for a tag to be "hijacked" like this?  If not, what can I do to resolve the issue?

I was thinking about retagging all of the questions, but in most cases, a tag such as [sql-lead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-lead) (doesn't exist yet) would be too specific--I think it should probably just be left as [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) and perhaps a tag for the particular DBMS.

Comment: *"Earlier I wrote a series on SQL Server Analytic Functions of SQL Server 2012."* i don't believe that should be in a tag  excerpt anyway.

Comment: @Memor-X Definitely not, which leaves me very concerned that half (two) of the reviewers have already approved it.

Comment: That edit has now been rejected so problem #1 out of the way.  Now the question is, what to with the tag and the question under it.

Comment: There aren't that many, and most--if not all--fit clearly into a popular category that people actually follow.  I assume I can just go through and retag them if we're able to get a consensus on that being the correct route.

Comment: The only lead I have on this tag is that it should sink like lead on water...

Comment: Should we even have this tag at all?

Comment: @zwol No, probably not; it doesn't refer to a specific technology.  I think the question at this point is whether we should split it into tags like [tag:sql-lead] and [tag:salesforce-lead] (which don't yet exist), or just go with tags like [tag:sql-server], [tag:oracle], and [tag:salesforce].  Note that LEAD/LAG is specific to Oracle and MSSQL; it's not found in any other SQL variants as far as I know.

Comment: That second edit should have been rejected as "Copied Content".. a quick search shows that it comes from [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/24/sql-server-solution-to-puzzle-simulate-lead-and-lag-without-using-sql-server-2012-analytic-function/).

Comment: @S.L.Barth Nice find.  That's a pretty unusual bit of text to copy, though.  Anyway, mysteries aside, we're still left with the matter of the tag.

Comment: @Zenexer: LEAD and LAG are standard SQL in the OLAP section of the standard.  Also found in DB2, Informix, probably PostgreSQL, probably Sybase, probably other DBMS too.

Comment: The tag edit makes me think the editor mistaken the tag wiki with the Documentation examples.

Comment: To supp @JonathanLeffler the most complete reference I found is [Wikipedia Database Capabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems#Database_capabilities) in the column windowing functions.

Comment: Good to know, but the tag is probably still a bit generic for that.  There are very few questions related to LEAD/LAG with this tag. [sql-lead] or similar would make more sense, if we were to go that route.

Comment: Marketing?  *Marketing??* ***MARKETING???***

Comment: Yes, @Will, there are actually developers who have gone to the dark side and work in marketing.

Comment: That doesn't make marketing questions on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @CodyGray My understanding is that they were questions about developing extensions, working with APIs, etc.  Salesforce is a popular marketing platform, so naturally there are a lot of developers interested in integrating with it.  The questions I saw were definitely on-topic, but it's certainly possible that some are more product-oriented.